# unable to generate RDLC report on client machine after deployment

Tags: c#, wpf, reportviewer, rdlc, reportviewer2008

I created an application that uses Microsoft.ReportViewer to show rdlc reports. The application is working fine on the dev. machine. now I am trying to deploy it on a client machine (windows 7) but when I generate the report nothing happens. Nothing at all. No error message and no exception. I am guessing this is due to missing Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms.dll/or framework?? I have set copyLocal=true for this dll but still no luck. what is the issue?

After putting message boxes at different places and catching exception I found out that ReportViewer needed to be installed on the client machine. These were the error messages that were showing up

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are copying over a .dll to the client machine?

Comment: @SethKitchen which dll?

Comment: I suggest you add some kind of text message to some of the relevant methods when calling the reporter to help figure out where exactly it goes wrong on the client pc. You'll have to give some more information in order to get the help that you seek. It's pretty much impossible to help you at ththis moment, as you can't provide an error and didn't post any relevant code

Comment: thanks for the suggestion this helped me proceed towards the solution :) I have updated the question and answered it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to install ReportViewer.exe on the client machines or needed to ship the dlls required with the installer. So I added the reference to the following dlls and marked CopyLocal=True and this solved my issue.

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.DLL</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.DLL</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```